# Does big integer in AWK only have 53 bits?

Tags: c++, linux, awk, bit-manipulation

Very strangely, I found that in awk, the big integer looks like has only 53 bits.Here is my example:

```
function bits2str(bits,data, mask)
{
    if (bits == 0)
        return "0"

    mask = 1
    for (; bits != 0; bits = rshift(bits, 1))
        data = (and(bits, mask) ? "1" : "0") data

    while ((length(data) % 8) != 0)
        data = "0" data

    return data
}

BEGIN{
    print 32,"\tlshift 48:\t", lshift(32,48), "\t", bits2str(lshift(32,48))
    print 429,"\tlshift 48:\t", lshift(429,48), "\t", bits2str(lshift(429,48))
}
```

and the output is:

```
32  lshift 48:   0   0
429     lshift 48:   3659174697238528    00001101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

but in c++, its output is:

```
32 lshift 48: 9007199254740992
429 lshift 48: 120752765008871424
```

After comparing the two output, I found that the awk's only have 53 bits, 
and then I researched the source code of gawk(start from line 3021 in the file named builtin.c, gawk 4.1.1, http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/), but I found no special operation on int.
So, what causes this? Why it is like this?

Answer (score 2):

In AWK, all numbers are stored in floating point.

From [Bitwise function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html):

> For all of these functions, first the double precision floating-point value is converted to the widest C unsigned integer type, then the bitwise operation is performed. If the result cannot be represented exactly as a C double, leading nonzero bits are removed one by one until it can be represented exactly. The result is then converted back into a C double.

Assuming IEEE-754 is used, `double`s can only represent integers up to 2<sup>53</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

if you use gawk, you need add the `-M` option for big number.

```
kent$ awk 'BEGIN{print lshift(32,48)}'
0

kent$ awk -M 'BEGIN{print lshift(32,48)}'
9007199254740992
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. My gawk/awk has no this option. My awk's version is GNU Awk 3.1.5, how about you?

Comment: In your question, you mentioned you checked gawk 4.1.1's codes. so I tested with 4.1.1. If you are working on 3.1.5, why you checked 4.1.1's codes? @xingwudao

Comment: Aha, sorry, it's such a stupid trying for me! I will install 4.1.1 on my machine.